# Where was Catholic doctrine defined before the Catechism?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

Apparently [the Catechism of the Catholic Church (CCC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechism_of_the_Catholic_Church) has only existed since 1992.

Was Catholic doctrine clearly defined in a specific set of sources before CCC? What would a priest have referred to in earlier times, if he had needed to check the stance of the Church on a specific detail?

Is it possible/practical/easy to find out what Catholic Church taught of a specific subject at a specific time in history?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the history of the [catechism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechism#Catholic_catechisms) is *substantially* longer than just 19 years! The catholic catechism dates for hundreds of years - one of the earlier "official" ones was promulgated in [1566](http://www.cin.org/users/james/ebooks/master/trent/tindex.htm).

Catechizing has been a long-standing practice (arguably, God told the Israelites to do that when He told them to write His law on the door posts and tell it to their children).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I somehow thought it was always called the Catechism of the Catholic Church.

Answer (score 6):

I asked this to a presenter in our diocese's [catechist training program](http://www.madisondiocese.org/Ministry/EvangelizationandCatechesis/SeatofWisdomDiocesanInstitute.aspx).  She said that the writings of the [Council of Trent](http://newadvent.org/cathen/15030c.htm) (1545-1563) were primarily used.  I guess that just helps Warren's answer.

Before that, I'd imagine we just looked at stained glass and/or frescoes...

Answer (score 2):

Dogmas and doctrines were written down from very early on. [Denzinger's *Sources of Catholic Dogma*](http://www.catecheticsonline.com/SourcesofDogma.php) is an excellent collection of important dogmas, ordered chronologically.